# Create field based on filter from another model prop / Mongoose , MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Basically I have User and School model in mongoose . I want to add teachers field to School by filtering User Model (it has role property) . Currently i tried this but i dont want all of users due to performance.

```
    import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import User from './user';
import userSchema from './user';

const schoolSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    users:[userSchema]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

schoolSchema.virtual('teachers').get(function(){
  return this.users.filter(user => user.role === 'principal')
})

const School = mongoose.models.School || mongoose.model('School', schoolSchema);

export default School;
```